# Iterating through Azure ItemPaged object

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

I am calling the `list` operation to retrieve the metadata values of a blob storage.
My code looks like:

```
blob_service_list = storage_client.blob_services.list('rg-exercise1', 'sa36730')
for items in blob_service_list:
    print((items.as_dict()))
```

What's happening in this case is that the returned output only contains the items which had a corresponding Azure object:

```
{'id': '/subscriptions/0601ba03-2e68-461a-a239-98cxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-exercise1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sa36730/blobServices/default', 'name': 'default', 'type': 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', 'sku': {'name': 'Standard_LRS', 'tier': 'Standard'}, 'cors': {'cors_rules': [{'allowed_origins': ['www.xyz.com'], 'allowed_methods': ['GET'], 'max_age_in_seconds': 0, 'exposed_headers': [''], 'allowed_headers': ['']}]}, 'delete_retention_policy': {'enabled': False}}
```

Where-as, If I do a simple print of items, the output is much larger:

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/0601ba03-2e68-461a-a239-98c1xxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-exercise1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sa36730/blobServices/default', 'name': 'default', 'type': 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', 'sku': <azure.mgmt.storage.v2021_06_01.models._models_py3.Sku object at 0x7ff2f8f1a520>, 'cors': <azure.mgmt.storage.v2021_06_01.models._models_py3.CorsRules object at 0x7ff2f8f1a640>, 'default_service_version': None, 'delete_retention_policy': <azure.mgmt.storage.v2021_06_01.models._models_py3.DeleteRetentionPolicy object at 0x7ff2f8f1a6d0>, 'is_versioning_enabled': None, 'automatic_snapshot_policy_enabled': None, 'change_feed': None, 'restore_policy': None, 'container_delete_retention_policy': None, 'last_access_time_tracking_policy': None}
```

Any value which is `None` has been removed from my example code. How can I extend my example code to include the None fields and have the final output as a list?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

If you need to include the **`None`** values in the dictionary you can follow the below code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

storage_client=StorageManagementClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),subscription_id="<your sub id>") 
blob_service_list = storage_client.blob_services.list('v-venkat-rg', 'venkat123')
for items in blob_service_list:
      items_dict = items.as_dict()
for key, value in items.__dict__.items():
        if value is None:
            items_dict[key] = value
            print(items_dict)
```

**Console:**

The above code executed with **`None`** value successfully.

[image]

Comment: this is very helpful. Can you also suggest a change so that my final output is a list.